# PHP block changed to comment by Wordpress?

Tags: php

I'm trying to print stuff with PHP using a simple echo:

```
<p>Test <?php echo 'Hello'; ?></p>
```

But "Hello" is not displayed.
When I inspect the webpage I can see that the PHP block has been commented out:

```
<p>Test <!--?php echo 'Hello'; ?--></p>
```

What happened?
Is it a bad practice to use PHP like that? (I'd like to display the date actually)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: are you trying to insert PHP code into post content? You can't do that, PHP has to be in a PHP file, if you want to embed PHP code on a page that runs you can't do it from the post editor. You need a page template/shortcode/widget/block

Comment: Hello @TomJNowell. Yes that's exactly what I am trying to do... I will into the pointers you gave me. Thanks!

Comment: note that there are plugins that will attempt to allow this, you may even be recommended them by poor hosting support staff, you should avoid them as they're dangerous and have major security consequences, as well as lots of common pitfalls. They are a development dead end and lead to lots of problems when used for anything more than adding trivial code.

Comment: Thanks again :)! I'm going to try with custom shortcodes. I hope this is not a bad idea.